# Shape Constrained Additive Model (Scam package) in Parsnip from Tidymodels

Tags: r, gam, tidymodels, mgcv, r-parsnip

The Scam package allows to create Shape Constrained Additive Models and uses some routines from the mgcv package.

The Parsnip package from the Tidymodels framework allows to create the following types of models using specific engines: https://www.tidymodels.org/find/parsnip/

Shape Constrained Additive Models aren't mentioned in this list. Is there a way to create such models using Parsnip?

Answer (score 1):

You could extend parsnip to fit this type of model. The best place to start is [How to build a parsnip model](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/develop/models/) on tidymodels.org.